# Args4j: Is it possible to required one and only option through two (or more) options?

Tags: java, args4j

Imagine I have this two options in args4j:

```
@Option(name = "-a")
boolean a;

@Option(name = "-b")
boolean b;
```

Is it possible, with annotation, to say that i want exactly either a or b (and only one of them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do with annotations only. But it is possible to do with annotation and one check.

You can use `forbids` in annotations to set At-Most-One constraint on your options.

```
@Options(name="-a1", forbids{"-a2", "-a3", /*...*/, "-aN"})
T a1;

@Options(name="-a2", forbids{"-a1", "-a3", /*...*/, "-aN"})
T a2;

/*...*/

@Options(name="-aN", forbids{"-a1", "-a2", /*...*/, "-a(N-1)"})
T aN;
```

And you can add one check in your class to set At-Least-One constraint on your options.

```
if (a1 == null && a2 == null && /*...*/ && aN == null) {
    throw new CmdLineException();
}
```

You can set exception message same with message shown when `required` option set for consistency.

Comment: All the "simple" CmdLineException ctors are deprecated now. The non-deprecated either require a Throwable, or are like the one you mentioned and require a Localizable. The problem is that all the code used to reproduce the missing required options are package-private and rely on the args4j ResourceBundle. Do you have a workaround?